# How to Dynamically Add New Cells To UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

Let's say a collection view's (or table view) number of items in a section property has been set to 10 (i.e., in a section, there are 10 cells) and two cells fill the whole view. This is what I want to implement:

While a user is viewing 9th and 10th cells if she swipes up, I want to show her new cells (i.e., 11th and 12th cells) by downloading corresponding cell information and inserting the cells to collection view. But until user views the last cell (10th) and swipes up; 11th and 12th cells' data shouldn't be downloaded and cells shouldn't be seen by the user (and when 11th and 12th cells are downloaded, if users swipe up again, this time 13th and 14th cells will be downloaded and so on).

I don't know if there is a name for this "action", so I couldn't search it appropriately. Is there an easy way to implement it?

Comment: It seems like you're looking for an infinitely scrolling table view. This is a well indexed subject on Google. Here's the Ray Wenderlich search result: https://www.raywenderlich.com/5786-uitableview-infinite-scrolling-tutorial

Comment: Hello Aaron! Yes, it is what I was looking for. Thanks a lot for letting me know what it is called; it helped a great deal.

Answer (score 2):

If you search google for "infinitely scrolling table view" as Aaron suggested or "pagination", you'll find lots of nicer and more sophisticated tutorials for implementing it in iOS. But I needed something simple and "just works" so here is how I implemented:

First, I define five variables which are:

```
let objectsToShowPerUpdate = 5 // I display 5 objects in the collection view, if user scroll down another 5 objects will be download and so on.

var objectIDs = [String]() // These are the IDs for to download objects to be viewed in collection views

var previouslyViewedCellIndexPaths = [Int]() // This will be explained below.
let objectNumberToBeDownloadedTotal = 10 // So I will download 10 objects in this case - I will first download 5 and if user scrolls down will download 5 more.

var objectsArray = [Object]() // will store Object items in this array.
```

In the viewDidLoad(), I will download and show first 5 objects (as set by objectsToShowPerUpdate).

```
downloadObjectIDsFunction { (downloadedObjectIDs) in
    self.objectIDs = downloadedObjectIDs

    downloadedObjectIDs.forEach({ (objectID) in
        downloadObject(objectID: objectID, { (object) in
            if self.objectsArray.count > self.objectsToShowPerUpdate - 1 { return }
            self.objectsArray.append(object)
            self.yourCollectionView.insertItems(at: [IndexPath(row: self.objectsArray.count - 1, section: 0)])
})
})
```

Set how many items your collection will contain:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return objectsArray.count
    }
```

Set how will your cells will be displayed:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: yourIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! YourCustomCell
    cell.titleLabel.text = objectsArray[indexPath.row].title
    return cell
}
```

Implement pagination here:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if (indexPath.row + 1) % objectsToShowPerUpdate == 0 && indexPath.row + 1 < objectIDs.count && !previouslyViewedCellIndexPaths.contains(indexPath.row + 1) && indexPath.row + 1 < objectNumberToBeDownloadedTotal {

        previouslyViewedCellIndexPaths.append(indexPath.row + 1) // So if user viewed the last cell before, we won't download same objects again.

        let indexes = (indexPath.row + 1)...(indexPath.row + objectsToShowPerUpdate)
        indexes.forEach { (index) in
            downloadObject(objectID: objectIDs[index], { (object) in
                self.objectsArray.append(object)
                self.yourCollectionView.insertItems(at: [IndexPath(row: self.objectsArray.count - 1, section: 0)])
            })
        }
    }
}
```

I will be happy if this help anyone!